# Render issue, part of character is missing

Tags: rendering

I'm new to blender and following lots of tutorials to get to grips with this programme. So far so good but I have hit an issue. I have created a character but when I go to render the image, all except for the central body shows? The body is showing as the original shaping blocks not the styled and coloured clothes. Am I missing something very obvious? I have attached a screen grab which shows my character and the render image on the left.
[image]

Comment: hello, we can't see any image

Comment: just added it now!

Comment: maybe you have an invisible object overlapping the body, press alt H in your 3D view or check the Outliner Render visibility (camera icon)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you have a hidden object obscuring the body of your character. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to *unhide* all hidden objects or check the outliner for objects with the "closed eye"-symbol:

[image: Hide in Outliner]

Comment: Thank you! I had a back up of the body which seemed to be causing the issue, I have saved another version and deleted the back up which has solved it, I appreciate your help!!!